# How do I stop proportional image scaling?

Tags: java, android, image, constraints, scale

I want my image to increase in height and width when the constraints expand, but I don't want them to do so proportionally. If only the height constraint expand, then only the image height should change (I'm trying to do a graphic background that expand with text size).

I have looked at the different xml options, eg. android:scaleType="centerInside", etc, but none seem to work the way I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

as described in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType):

> fitXY     Scale the image using FILL.
>
> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.